# Mojolicious doesn't load absolute javascript and CSS files

Tags: gnuplot, mojolicious

I'm trying to use Gnuplot to create "canvas" HTML documents. When I put one into public/, Mojolicious generates 404's on the javascript and CSS files in /usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2/js. Without modifying the HTML output, how can I get these files to load properly?

HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gnuplot Canvas Graph</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2/js/canvastext.js"></script>
<script src="/usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2/js/gnuplot_common.js"></script>
<script src="/usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2/js/gnuplot_dashedlines.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

Mojolicious error:

```
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54125] [10258] [debug] GET "/usr/share/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2/js/canvastext.js" (f301442a)
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54202] [10258] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54218] [10258] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54228] [10258] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/debug.html.ep"
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54337] [10258] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/menubar.html.ep"
[2019-04-02 16:02:55.54890] [10258] [debug] 404 Not Found (0.007638s, 130.924/s)
```

I know it's converting these filepaths into a URL, but I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gnuplot canvas terminal has an option "jsdir" for exactly this reason:

```
gnuplot> set term canvas jsdir 'http://wherever/the/scripts/live/'
```

The output *.html then contains lines like

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="http://wherever/the/scripts/live/canvasmath.js"></script>
<script src="http://wherever/the/scripts/live/gnuplot_common.js"></script>
<script src="http://wherever/the/scripts/live/gnuplot_dashedlines.js"></script>
<script src="http://wherever/the/scripts/live/gnuplot_mouse.js"></script>
```